# Getting the sum of a specific number in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, cell

I just want to get the sum of all the values on the left side and not include the date.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Example Ans:]

Hey, Try this, even the data is inconsistent with more spaces, this will work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(A2:A6,SEARCH("-",SUBSTITUTE(A2:A6," ",""))-1)+0)
```

Comment: Thank you this works well all the other solution keeps giving me an error message. How can I make this formula work even if the selected cell doesn't have any data in it because I just tried it and it works but if there is a selected cell that is empty it doesn't show the Sum. Thank you

Comment: @KaitoKid handling null/empty values https://techfura.medium.com/how-to-coalesce-excel-data-89e639d1248f#:~:text=How%20to%20Coalesce%20Excel%20Data%20The%20Coalesce%20function,leave%20non-%20blank%20and%20non-empty%20string%20values%20unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SUMPRODUCT()`. Assuming, you have space after value.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A4,SEARCH(" ",A1:A4)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
=SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(A1:A4," "))
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation to the previous proposals for two reasons:

1. Don’t need to invoke SUMPRODUCT().  If `- -` has been used to force enumeration, then SUM() is sufficient.
2. While TEXTSPLIT() works, you’ll run into problems if your column length is one.  TEXTSPLIT will create a horizontal array with multiple values if applied to a range with only one row, producing ambiguity and a potential error.

Thus:

`=SUM(--TEXTBEFORE(A2:A6," "))`

is more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

Textsplit, Textbefore functions are available on office365. If the user is not using office365, sumproduct would be the preferrable choice.